# how to pass a parameter in _layout.cshtml in actionLink asp.net MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

In my _layout.cshtml i want to add a menu like that:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "User", new {e_id ="myemail@email.com")
```

i want to pass

```
@Context.User.Identity.Name
```

as e_id. Can i pass it in that way?? if not then what is the other way?When I hard coded like that:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "User", new { e_id="awladliton@gmail.com"})
```

it don't redirect me in the User controller Details action.when i give URL like that:

```
http://localhost:48096/User/Details?e_id=awladliton@gmail.com
```

It Works Fine.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like this

```
@Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "User", new { e_id="Context.User.Identity.Name},null)
```

It uses this overload

```
public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(
    this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
    string linkText,
    string actionName,
    string controllerName,
    Object routeValues,
    Object htmlAttributes
)
```

If you want to pass any custom HTML attributes to the link element, you can replace the fifth parameter with that

Ex :

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "User", new { e_id="yourvalue"},new {@class="myCSsClassName"})
```

Comment: Thanks @Shyju, How should i get my routeValues,HtmlAttributes??? please describe a little bit more....

Comment: Thanks @Shyju, My actionLink is now works as : <<li> @Html.ActionLink("Profile", "Details", "User", new { e_id=Context.User.Identity.Name},null) </li>

Comment: @AwladLiton Did it fix your problem ?